# Titanium and Javascript anonymous function scope

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium

I am trying to call the `forwardGeocoder` function in titanium, but I am having some issues with retrieving the results, consider the following code :-

```
x = 0;

Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(startTextFieldContents, function(evt) {
    var startPin = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({
        longitude   :   evt.longitude,
        latitude    :   evt.latitude,
        pincolor    :   Ti.Map.ANNOTATION_GREEN
    });
    
    var startPinLocation = {
        longitude       : evt.longitude,
        latitude        : evt.latitude
    }
    
    mapview.addAnnotation(startPin);
    x = 1;
});

Ti.API.log('X = ' + x);
```

If you take a look at X, when I log this out it is ALWAYS equal to 0 even though I am setting it inside my anonymous function as 1, and because this is a function call with an anonymous function as an argument I am struggling to figure out how to retrieve that value and make it available outside the forwardGeocoder.

To resolve this, based on what was said in this post I used the following code:

```
var completed = 0;
        
        Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(startTextFieldContents, function(evt) {
            var startPin = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({
                longitude   :   evt.longitude,
                latitude    :   evt.latitude,
                pincolor    :   Ti.Map.ANNOTATION_GREEN
            });
            
            startPinLocation = {
                longitude       : evt.longitude,
                latitude        : evt.latitude
            }
            
            mapview.addAnnotation(startPin);
            ++completed;
            
            if (completed === 1) {
                Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(finishTextFieldContents, function(evt) {
                    var finishPin = Ti.Map.createAnnotation({
                        longitude   :   evt.longitude,
                        latitude    :   evt.latitude,
                        pincolor    :   Ti.Map.ANNOTATION_RED
                    });
            
                    finishPinLocation = {
                        longitude       : evt.longitude,
                        latitude        : evt.latitude
                    }
            
                    mapview.addAnnotation(finishPin);
                    
                    mapview.addRoute({
                        name : 'Route',
                        points : [startPinLocation, finishPinLocation],
                        color : 'green',
                        width : 1
                    });
                    
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's just like the last question of yours I commented on. It's asynchronous. So instead of having your code work line by line, which is what you're used to, you have to start working with an event-driven model. The value will be available at some point in time when the data is fetched from the server. To that end you pass in a function, from within which the value will be available, and henceforth to all other code. Your log (and use of the values) must then come from **within** the anonymous function you pass in.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and in my previous issue I was able to use my log inside the async event function to get at my results, the problem here is that I am actually running two forwardGeocoders, one for a start location and one for an end location, I then want to pass them into another function which will calculate the route between them, so the critical issue is that I need both the start and end location variables available, but they are within separate events, so it seems I can get to one, but not the other.

Comment: You must put them all inside each other. When the start location has been found, find the end location. When the end location has been found you can calculate the route as you have all the data available.

Comment: Try and shift your paradigm. Agreed, that is a slightly trickier problem, so let's think of some solutions. I'll post a few suggestions below, in the meantime, update the question with the details in your comment.

Comment: @Juhana that was my initial thought, but the issue is that they are still not available to each other at the same time.

Comment: @davin yeah, I think you are correct as it is a paradigm shift in terms of my own mindset, event-driven programming is still a reasonably new concept to me, and while I can see why this isn't working I can't yet come to a logical solution.  Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as Juhana suggested to nest the calls. The problem is that that is slow. You wait for a round-trip from the server and only then begin the next round trip, and only after 2 *synchronous* (i.e. non-parallel) round-trips do you perform the required task. It would be necessary if the data were dependent on each other, although it sounds like they aren't

As such, you can do as follows:

```
var completed = 0, values = [];

function handle(data){
   values.push(data);
   ++completed;
   if (completed === 2) {
      dataReadySoLetsDoStuff();
   }
}

fetchFromServer(params1, handle);
fetchFromServer(params2, handle);

function dataReadySoLetsDoStuff() {
   // both values are ready
}
```

Do you see how that will work asynchronously? There is a small problem that you can't distinguish between the values because their order isn't guaranteed, but you can easily change `handle` (currying, binding or wrapping for example) to fix that.

You can use other approaches, although they are all based on the same idea - count completed tasks until I guarantee all are done, and then perform the task we wanted to do...

Comment: Yeah, this was the way I was looking at doing it but I see all sorts of issues doing it that way, mainly the speed issue would be a problem, and I am still not sure I would be able to get both locations from the forwardGeocoder next to each other at the same time.

Comment: @bagwaa, I don't see any issues, let alone "all sorts" of them. What speed issues?

Comment: The speed issue I was referring to was "The problem is that that is slow. You wait for a round-trip from the server and only then begin the next round trip"

Comment: I think I have this sorted now based on the advice on here, basically, nest them and check for the event completion, will post what I have ended up with.

Comment: @bagwaa, feel free to do whatever you want, although I suggest *not* nesting the calls, since they're independent. Your solution will work, although it doesn't need a completion count to work. You can remove that variable - the nesting takes care of that for you, at the cost of a slower UX.